# Linux snap confinement - access usb device

Tags: linux, usb, udev

Currently I'm struggling to connect to a USB device from a confined snap environment, not knowing how to approach the problem anymore, but also still learning about snap confinements / udev rules etc.

In a nutshell, this is what I've already tried and verified:

- Raw-usb slot-plug is connected between snapd and the developed snap (verifying with snap interfaces)
- The usb device is being interfaced with via a library, where the library's dependencies can be viewed via readelf:

[image: library dependencies]

- These dependencies are met, and the binary successfully runs within classic snap environment, with console output from the binary:

[image: console reply]

- When running this binary from the snap environment, it also executes (so no dependency issues), but the USB devices isn't picked up.
- The device does however register as /dev when plugged in:

[image: registering device]

- with ID when calling lsusb:

[image: device ID]

- A udev rules file is specified for the device. By implementing the device's interfacing binary within classic snap environment it doesn't matter to include these udev rule. Did however paste the lines (as follows) into the created snap's rule file (/etc/udev/rules.d/.rules) and rebooted the system, but didn't make a difference.:

> ENV{hotplugscript}="/etc/.mplab_ide/mchplinusbdevice"
>
> ACTION!="add", GOTO="check_remove"
>      SUBSYSTEM=="usb_device", GOTO="check_add"
>      SUBSYSTEM!="usb", GOTO="rules_end"
>
> LABEL="check_add"
>
> ATTR{idVendor}=="04d8", MODE="666", RUN+="%E{hotplugscript} add"
>      GOTO="rules_end"
>
> LABEL="check_remove"
>
> ACTION=="remove", RUN+="%E{hotplugscript} remove %E{PRODUCT}"
>
> LABEL="rules_end"

but for instance, also not finding a directory `/etc/.mplab_ide/mchplinusbdevice` and uncertain what everything means and if implemented correctly.

Hope that my explanations make sense. Any advice, or additional debugging tips will be greatly appreciated. Have no idea how to approach the problem further

Comment: [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1034065/963426) might be useful.

Comment: Thanks for the link, but quickly checking the answer, referring to snap interfaces, which I ensured via connecting to 'raw-usb' plugs. If this is in fact a interfaces issue (where I interpreted the problem more to be with regards to snap rules files), I would need to see different snap slot / plug types and confirm if I'm connecting the right thing. But as the device registered as a hidraw0 device under _/dev_ I presumed _raw-usb_ plugs as the correct interface entity